# How to freeze my Python code with PyInstaller when the exe says it miss some files?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am using Python 3.7.9 with Pyinstaller 5.0.1

I am trying to freeze my code which uses pyshadow.
When I execute it from Pycharm it works fine.
When I execute the exe after I freezed the code, I get this error:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI233082\\pyshadow\\resources\\querySelector.js`

This could be a common issue when your python code uses some specific module that needs some third files. In my case, it is about pyshadow missing a JS file.

So I add this file 'querySelector.js' in the freezing command:

`pyinstaller --onefile -F --uac-admin --icon="icon_PhoneBot_256.ico" --clean --noconsole  --add-data "querySelector.js;." main.py`

But I still get the same error.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to rokm. I get his help from the git forum of the PyInstaller developer (full details here: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/discussions/6905). I publish his answer here in case someone has the same issue.

I had to add the parameter:

```
--collect-data pyshadow
```

So my final command is:

```
pyinstaller --onefile -F --uac-admin --icon="icon_PhoneBot_256.ico" --clean --noconsole  --collect-data pyshadow main.py
```

ANd it works like a charm!